# Outlook 2010 Save Internet Headers for all Emails

Tags: outlook

I am wondering how can I get the internet headers from ALL of the emails from a PST (Outlook 2010).

Currently I can only do this if I go to each email, Properties, Internet Headers, right click, Select All, Copy.

Comment: Is this a programming question?

Comment: I was thinking to write code to get the email headers but i ended up using OutlookSpy and was much easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OutlookSpy was the solution and did not have to write any code.